# PushModalAsync allows multiple presses of button, how can I make it only able to click once?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to use

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PageName);
```

but it allows for the button to be pressed multiple times meaning multiple of the same page will appear on the app, I have it working for `PushAsync` but I would like some pages to use `PushModalAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

Add await in front of Navigation.pushmodelasync since it's an asynchronize call.

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PageName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are binding your button to a command this would probably be the most convenient solution:

```
    public class AwaitingCommand : ICommand
    {
        private bool _isBusy;

        private Action<object> _callback;

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public AwaitingCommand(Action<object> callback)
        {
            _callback = callback;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return !_isBusy;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public async void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (!_isBusy)
            {
                SetBusy(true);
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _callback?.Invoke(parameter), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                SetBusy(false);
            }
        }

        private void SetBusy(bool busy)
        {
            _isBusy = busy;
            CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
```

Now when creating an instance of the command all you do is pass a delegate with the Navigation call and the command will make sure to await the result of the call, before it gets unlocked for further calls again.

So somewhere you'll write code like

```
MyNavigationButton = new AwaitingCommand(() => Navigation.PushModalAsync(yourpage));
```